# Windows 8 Permissions Issue

Tags: c#, windows-8, permissions

I've created an installer for an application using WiX, and everything is working fine except when I test on Windows 8.

As part of some operations done after the installation itself, I attach a database and then encrypt it, while operating under an impersonated user on the system, created for the application.

The database files are stored in \ProgramData, and attempting encryption results in System.UnauthorizedAccessException. Starting the newly created service also fails, with System.InvalidOperationException because Access Is Denied.

Both of these operations have been attempted using System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand as well as Assert, but with no luck.

UAC is disabled and the installer is launched as an administrator. Is there a way around this failure in Windows 8? This is not a metro app.

Comment: No success even with "requireAdministrator" in the app.manifest.

Comment: Solved. Finally found a reference online that users have full access to ProgramData but only if that user initially created the file. The impersonated user had not originally placed the file, but the system. Fixing that, the encryption is successful.